# Conditional coloring of geom_path in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following simplified data frame, which contains four paths:

```
df <- read.table(text="id x y
                 a 1 1
                 a 2 2.0
                 a 2 3.1
                 a 3.2 4
                 b 1.0 1
                 b 2 0
                 b 2 -1
                 b 3 -3
                 c 1 1
                 c 0 0
                 c 0 -1
                 c -1 -2
                 d 1 1
                 d 0 1
                 d -1 0
                 d -2 0", header=TRUE)
```

I am able to plot the paths, using ggplots' `geom_path()` function:

```
ggplot(data = df) +
   geom_path(aes(x = x, y = y, color = id))
```

**Question**

How do I color the paths that have a Y-value of over 2 in red (or even better, in red scales in case of multiple paths), while coloring the others in different greyscales? I am able to manually alter the colors of the lines, but I have plots with 3 up to 50+ paths, so I am looking for a more automated solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to add a colour column for each path before passing the data frame into `ggplot`: for example, you could assign each path a colour name in `luv_colours`, which can be passed into an `identity` colour scale. The example below does this with `dplyr`.

```
n_ids <- length(unique(df$id))

group_by(df, id) %>% 
  mutate(col = if (any(y>2)) "red" else paste0("gray", round(match(id, letters) * 60/n_ids))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_path(aes(x, y, colour = col, lty = id)) + 
  scale_colour_identity()
```

`n_ids` is used to spread the grayscale values over most of the scale, leaving out the values close to white. This should work if `n_ids <= 50`, since `60/n_ids > 1`, and therefore two paths can't have their gray number be the same after rounding.

[image: Example]

Line types are used here for the legend, because using colour runs into problems if there's more than one red path. This not ideal, because there are not many line types. I'd therefore recommend that, instead of colouring the key paths red, you use a different line type, reserving colour for the path id since there are many more colours than line types.

```
group_by(df, id) %>% 
  mutate(lty = if (any(y>2)) "solid" else "dashed") %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_path(aes(x, y, colour = id, lty = lty)) + 
  scale_linetype_identity()
```

[image: Example 2]

This also has the advantage of the number of paths not being limited by the number of grayscale colours.

If the path IDs have a meaningful order, you could look at using a colour palette different to the default, such as `scale_color_brewer()` or `scale_color_viridis_d()`.

EDIT: You could also introduce several shades of red, and use them in a similar way to how I handled the grayscale for different paths. I'd still recommend against this in favour of my alternative for two reasons:

1. Handling colours in this way is a pain.
2. It still has the same underlying problem, which is that you're trying to map several features of the paths (y > 2, id) onto a single graphical feature (colour).

This is all predicated on you wanting to identify each path uniquely. If not, you can just do this:

```
group_by(df, id) %>% 
  mutate(col = if (any(y>2)) "red" else "black") %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_path(aes(x, y, colour = col, group = id)) + 
  scale_colour_identity()
```

[image: Example 3]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear to me but you can create a condition and then color the item based on it.

```
df <- read.table(text="id x y
             a 1 1
             a 2 2.0
             a 2 3.1
             a 3.2 4
             b 1.0 1
             b 2 0
             b 2 -1
             b 3 -3
             c 1 1
             c 0 0
             c 0 -1
             c -1 -2
             d 1 1
             d 0 1
             d -1 0
             d -2 0", header=TRUE) 
df$condition <- ifelse(df$y>2,"Yes","No")


ggplot(data = df) + geom_path(aes(x = x, y = y, color = condition))
```